# Android - optimal way to present a list of appointments

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I am developing an Android app for doctors. Somewhere in the app, the doctor can choose to view all of her appointments for one given month.

The thing is that one specific patient may have more than 1 appointment with the doctor in that month, maybe 2, 3 or even more. And let's say the doctor doesn't have just 1 patient, but lots of them.

So, we have let's say 10 different patients, each of them having 3 different appointments for a given month with their doctor. That sums up to 10x3=30 appointments for this particular month.

I thought of managing appointments using a `ListView` (or even a `RecyclerView`) with some sort of custom `Item views`. The thing is that I don't think that's going to be the optimal way to present ordered, important data to the doctor. Nor is it going to be visually appealing (should I say appalling?).

Maybe there is any kind of Android UI component that helps me with this and I am missing it.

Answer (score 0):

If I was doing such app, I would use ListView with patients and times of appointment at each patient view. Doctor should tap a patient to view its appointments in detail.

Comment: May you be more specific with your answer? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean using an `ExpandableListView`?